# Why release Second ViewController just after creating it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ‘release’ means in this situation on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307816/what-does-release-means-in-this-situation-on-iphone)

I'm watching [this tutorial](http://vimeo.com/1450817) on switching 2 views.

I don't understand the 3rd instruction (weirdly the author doesn't explain it!): why `release` just after `alloc`?

```
SecondViewController *aSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:init];
[self setSecondViewController:aSecondView];
[aSecondView release];
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3307816/1047258

Comment: I know what retain means but I don't understand in this context of switching views precisely.

Comment: the secondViewController is a retain property

Answer (score 2):

Because the receiver (`self`) must be retaining the view controller in its `setSecondViewController:` implementation.